# Nhibernate Criteria for the given query?

Tags: asp.net, nhibernate

I am trying to create Nhibernate criteria for the follwing query but not getting the right idea. Plz guide

```
SELECT PEH.ResponseStatus FROM PatientEligibilityHistory PEH WHERE PEH.PatientId = " + patientId + " AND PEH.PayorId = " + payorId  + " AND PEH.DateOfService = '" + dateOfService + "' AND PEH.Insured_Id = '" + insuredId + "' HAVING PEH.ResponseDateTime = MAX(PEH.ResponseDateTime)
```

I am unable to understand how to create criteria for having clause using max.

Comment: ICriteria criteria = session.CreateCriteria(typeof(PatientEligibilityHistory));
            criteria.Add(Expression.And(Expression.In("PatientId", patientList), Expression.In("PatientCaseId", patientCaseList)));
criteria.Add(Expression.And(Expression.In("PayorId", payorList), Expression.In("InsuredId", insuredList)));
            criteria.SetProjection(Projections.RowCount());
But now I have to add having clause as metioned in query which I am unale to do.

Answer (score 1):

you need a correlated subquery

```
DetachedCriteria query = DetachedCriteria.For<PatientEligibilityHistory>()
    .Add(Expression.In("PatientId", patientList))
    .Add(Expression.In("PatientCaseId", patientCaseList))
    .Add(Expression.In("PayorId", payorList))
    .Add(Expression.In("InsuredId", insuredList));

DetachedCriteria subquery = CriteriaTransformer.Clone(query).SetProjection(Projections.Max("ResponseDateTime"));

ICriteria criteria = query.GetExecutableCriteria(session)
    .Add(Subquery.Eq("ResponseDateTime", subquery));
    .SetProjection(Projections.Max("ResponseStatus"));
```